# Numerical integration of an integrand including the dirac delta function

Tags: dirac-delta, numerical-calculus

I have the following,

$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\xi \, R(\xi) \, \delta[\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{R}(\xi)]$$

I need to evaluate this numerically on a series of grids. The dirac delta function serves to interpolate between two grids, a regular spacial grid (for $\mathbf{r}$) and the $\xi$ grid, which has length $N_\xi$. The two grids are mapped together by finding the spacial position given by $\xi$, e.g. $\mathbf{R}(\xi)$. The spacial grid and the $\xi$ position do not line up perfectly, and I interpolate between the two with a nearest neighbor approach (I believe this is implied by the dirac delta).
The integral is calculated by finding the point in the $\mathbf{r}$ grid closest to $\mathbf{R}(\xi)$ and adding $R(\xi)$ to it for all points in the $\xi$ grid.

Unfortunately, my result ends up being exactly $\frac{N_\xi}{2\pi}$ too large, and I think this has to do with translating the integral over $\xi$ into a sum (something to do with the dirac delta function?).

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: This isn't dimensionally consistent; the vector Dirac delta needs to be integrated on a volume, not an interval. If you want to integrate $d\xi$ then you need to choose a scalar function that vanishes exactly on the zero vector and compose the delta function with that. But the result will depend on which scalar function you chose, which you probably don't want. It might help for you to change the question to fill us in on how you got to this stage analytically.

Comment: This equation came from a paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.08471.pdf), see equation 12. I simplified the equation to remove unnecessary detail. Technically, what I am trying to do here is map an elliptical orbit (defined on grids in phase space) into physical space grid. $\xi$ is eccentric anomaly here.

Comment: Unless there is some weird notation where a vector delta function is being inappropriately used, this inner integral has a result that still has delta function character i.e. it still isolates points in the $dA$ and $dB$ integrals.

Comment: Are there finitely many solutions to $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{R}(\xi;A,B)$ in $(\xi,A,B)$ space? (Keep in mind this is a question about the real analysis not the numerical analysis).

Comment: I confess that I'm not sure how to answer that. A given ($\xi$, $A$, $B$) will map to a single $(x, y, z)$ through equation 8 in the previously mentioned paper. Many (infinite?) ($\xi$, $A$, $B$) can map to the same $(x, y, z)$ (e.g. an infinite number of orbits can have the same periapsis position with different semi-major axis and eccentricity). I'll have to think about this more.